# Retrieving Content from a Sub Content

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2k8 and have a table that needs to be able to pull dynamic content.
So, I was thinking of having 2 columns which would act like a Parent and Child.

```
ContentId - SubContentId - ContentInfo
100         100            data here
101         100            data here
102         100            data here
103         100            data here
```

So, although the ContentId is incrementing, the SubContentId relates to the Parent ContentId of 100.  So if I SELECT ContentId 100, I'd check the SubContentId for this number as well in order to pull back all of the details for ContentId 100.  Is this approach sensible?  Am I way of the mark?

Comment: Have you got content and subcontent mixed up? (Also what happens when you run a select command and what did you expect?)

Comment: Well, I don't think that I have.  I could then have a SubContentId of 101 so I would then pick up all of the SubContent data for 101 and 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a self referencing table. This isn't all bad. All you have to do is create a query like this.

`SELECT * FROM content where subcontentID = contentID AND contentID = @contentID`

The results will be all the content records that have the specified contentID

An ordered result set might be nice if you need to see all the data too.

```
SELECT * FROM content where subcontentID = contentID ORDER BY subcontentID,contentID
```

This will give you all the content records keeping all the subcontent records together in order.

This is not bad at all it saves from creating a duplicate table with the same schema.

Comment: I need to add another column in so I can use this as a Parent column.  I'd like all of the data (from 100 - 105) to all be associated with the first item, 100.

Answer (score 1):

Create, setup, test:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    ContentID int, SubContentID int, ContentInfo varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (100, 100, 'info 1')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (101, 100, 'info 2')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (102, 100, 'info 3')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (103, 100, 'info 4')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (104, 100, 'info 5')

SELECT ContentInfo, 
          (SELECT ContentInfo + ',' as "data()"  
           FROM #tmp x 
           WHERE x.SubContentID = z.ContentID FOR XML PATH('')
          ) As [SubContent]  
FROM #tmp z
WHERE ContentID = 100
```

Comment: From this great example, I've seen that I need another column so I can select all of the 100's for example.  Thanks! :o)